# java.lang.NullPointerException: No API environment is registered for this thread

Tags: java, eclipse, google-app-engine, gwt

I have gwt 2.6.1 application which runs successfully in kepler with google app engine sdk 1.9.7. now i have updated [Cloud Tools for Eclipse](https://cloud.google.com/eclipse/docs/)  and [GWT Eclipse Plugin](http://gwt-plugins.github.io/documentation/) 
Now i have improted existing project in this new version then when i run this project with GWT development mode with jetty then i got below exception

```
2017-11-14 13:09:35.108:WARN:oejw.WebAppContext:Failed startup of context c.g.g.d.s.j.WebAppContextWithReload{/,file:/C:/NEON%20Projects/14%20nov%20existing%20project/Slick%20Erp/war/},C:\NEON Projects\14 nov existing project\Slick Erp\war
java.lang.NullPointerException: No API environment is registered for this thread.
    at com.google.appengine.api.datastore.DatastoreApiHelper.getCurrentAppId(DatastoreApiHelper.java:144)
    at com.google.appengine.api.datastore.DatastoreApiHelper.getCurrentAppIdNamespace(DatastoreApiHelper.java:160)
    at com.google.appengine.api.datastore.Query.<init>(Query.java:210)
    at com.google.appengine.api.datastore.Query.<init>(Query.java:141)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.QueryImpl.<init>(QueryImpl.java:69)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.LoadTypeImpl.createQuery(LoadTypeImpl.java:48)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.Queryable.list(Queryable.java:55)
    at com.slicktechnologies.server.MyWarmup.contextInitialized(MyWarmup.java:352)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.callContextInitialized(ContextHandler.java:782)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.callContextInitialized(ServletContextHandler.java:424)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.startContext(ContextHandler.java:774)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.startContext(ServletContextHandler.java:249)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1242)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:717)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:494)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.jetty.JettyLauncher$WebAppContextWithReload.doStart(JettyLauncher.java:541)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:64)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:95)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.RequestLogHandler.doStart(RequestLogHandler.java:162)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:64)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:95)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:282)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:64)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.jetty.JettyLauncher.start(JettyLauncher.java:740)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.DevMode.doStartUpServer(DevMode.java:632)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.DevModeBase.startUp(DevModeBase.java:1054)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.DevModeBase.run(DevModeBase.java:836)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.DevMode.main(DevMode.java:413)
```

any help ? how to solve this exception ?

Answer (score 1):

You need to launch using the App Engine development server.  Fortunately it can serve GWT applications, but you need to enable the GWT Super Dev Mode builder on your project.  See the Cloud Tools for Eclipse docs on [*Migrating from the Google Plugin for Eclipse*](https://cloud.google.com/eclipse/docs/migrating-gpe#gwt_wzxhzdk2wzxhzdk3).

Comment: Thank you for your valuable response.  I did using above instruction first i have imported existing project into new environment eclipse then i have converted in app engine standard  Configure > Convert to App Engine Project.  then i also enable Configure > Enable GWT SDM builder. now i run my application then mywarmup servlet getting executed but my application GWT entry point class is not getting executed. Why my app is not getting run ? any help